# Spectrum of a Composition with an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ two Banach spaces. Given $T:X\rightarrow X$ a bounded linear operator and $A:Y\rightarrow X$ an isometry, is it true that

$$\sigma(T)=\sigma(T\circ A)$$

where $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of the operator $T$?

I don't have any idea how to start, and even I don't know if this is true.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: think about the case $T=I$.

Comment: True! It was so easy. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be more sensible to look at $\sigma(A^{-1} \circ T \circ A)$